# phonegap-splash screen appears on click of android device BACK button

Tags: cordova

Have implemented phonegap application for android/ios & blackberry, with phonegap version-1.3, facing problem with the android splash screen.

1. when am on any page of the application, and start using device BACK button, the android SPLASH screen appears/pops sometimes, and then the previously accessed page is shown.

   ```
   function onBackKeyPress() {
       history.back();
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. when any textview is clicked/focused, the splash screen is shown, and the input box flickers.

Comment: Is there any solution for above question ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread :

[splash screen appears on click of android device BACK button — Created using PhoneGap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393357/splash-screen-appears-on-click-of-android-device-back-button-created-using-ph