# splash screen appears on click of android device BACK button -- Created using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We have created a phonegap application for android with phonegap version-1.3.

1. When I am on any page of the application, and start using the device BACK button, the Android SPLASH screen appears/pops sometimes, and then the previously accessed page is shown.

   function onBackKeyPress()
2. Sometimes when i click on some links which open the browser, and after i click on back button, its Showing Splash screen and relaunch the application.

Is there any other function we can use for back button?

Comment: its a small problem, in our application there is some URL links are there. when user click on those links its open the browser in mobile. Now when i click on back button, some time it will take me to same screen and some time it will take me to Splash screen and relaunch the application

Answer (score 2):

From the activity before splash screen from which you wish to exit application override onBackpress.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Hi Rakshi, Thanks for help, and one more doubt i have, whenever i click on Text box, Sometimes the Splash screen comes there also. Is there any method i can use there.

Comment: that might be because the activity where you clicked the editbox is crashing so it it is taking to previous activity.

Comment: i am using html5 with phonegap, and the textbox is an html5 <input>, and when i click on the textbox , the splash screen pops and disappears. this happens only in tablet

Comment: I did this on a native (not phonegap) app, and it worked, however what this probably does, is to resume the "launcher" app, which means that the app isn't killed, so next time I run it, it skips the splash screen. Is there any way to *gracefully* kill the app?

Comment: The below code will kill the process in the OS,int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);